# Double quotes inside inner-syntax comment

Tags: syntax, comments, isabelle

The `"` character, when placed inside a comment in a double-quoted piece of Isabelle's inner-syntax, does not behave as I would expect. To clarify: in the following function definition, I would expect `the "at" sign` to be parsed as a comment. In fact, Isabelle matches the first `"` character in the comment with the `"` at the start of that line, thus leading to a syntax error.

```
fun reverse where 
  "reverse [] = []"
| "reverse (x#xs) = reverse xs @ (* the "at" sign *) [x]"
```

I can work around this limitation by writing `(* the 'at' sign *)`, but I'd rather understand what's really going on. So what's the right way to write this sort of comment inside an Isabelle term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it would work with an escape character, like \" ?

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, that works. I'll wait a little before accepting your answer, just because I remain a bit uncomfortable about having to escape the quotes -- when I'm inside a comment, it feels like I shouldn't have to...

Comment: The need for escaped quotes here is a result of Isabelle's combination of outer and inner syntax, which are handled by separate parsers. The outer parser doesn't know anything about inner-syntax comments, so it parses this example as two separate quoted strings.

Comment: This is all perfectly normal according to SML and Isar syntax.  Inside double quotes you need escapes.  Truely surprising things can happen in OCaml and Coq, when comments and quotes are combined.